# How do i get the dynamic table displayed as a popup?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup, bootstrap-modal

I have this piece of code which computes the difference between the rows of two selected tables and display the result on click of button. How can I display the result in a pop up? Basically I want the resultant table to come as popup, so that when we close the popup the tables checkbox are again reset.

Edit: I tried using modals but it seems to be not working. Can anyone please help where I am going wrong

```js
var selectedRows = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
        limit = 0; //set limit

        checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxdiv input[type="checkbox"]');
        function checker(elem) {
            if (elem.checked) {
                limit++;
            } else {
                limit--;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

                if (limit == 2) {
                    if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
                        checkboxes[i].disabled = true;

                    }

                } else {

                    if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
                        checkboxes[i].disabled = false;
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].onclick = function () {
                checker(this);
            }
        }

        var checkedArray;
        function myFunction(event) {
            event.target.parentElement.parentElement.className =
                event.target.checked ? 'selected' : '';

            var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
            checkedArray = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i].type === 'checkbox' && elements[i].checked) {
                    checkedArray.push(elements[i].id);
                }
            }
            console.log(checkedArray);
        }

        $(".btn[data-target='#myModal']").click(function() {
 var modalBody = $('<div id="modalContent"></div>');
var table;
            const buildTable = (arr) => {
                table = document.querySelector("#diff-table");
                if (table) table.remove();

                table = document.createElement("table");
                table.id = "diff-table";
                const thead = document.createElement("thead"),
                    thA = document.createElement("th"),
                    thB = document.createElement("th"),
                    thDiff = document.createElement("th");
                thA.innerText = "Plan A";
                thB.innerText = "Plan B";
                thDiff.innerText = "Difference";
                thead.append(thA, thB, thDiff);
                table.append(thead);

                arr.forEach((i) => {
                    const tr = document.createElement("tr"),
                        tdA = document.createElement("td"),
                        tdB = document.createElement("td"),
                        tdDiff = document.createElement("td");
                    tdA.innerText = "$" + i["planA"];
                    tdB.innerText = "$" + i["planB"];
                    tdDiff.innerText = "$" + i["diff"];
                    tr.append(tdA, tdB, tdDiff);
                    table.append(tr);
                });

                document.body.append(table);
            };
            const checked = document.querySelectorAll(":checked"),
                arr = [];
            if (checked.length !== 2) return;
            const plans = document.querySelectorAll(":checked"),     
            planA = plans[0].closest("table").querySelectorAll("td"),    
             planB = plans[1].closest("table").querySelectorAll("td");

            planA.forEach((cell, i) => {
                const valA = +cell.innerText.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
                const valB = +planB[i].innerText.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
                arr.push({ planA: valA, planB: valB, diff: valA - valB });
            });

            buildTable(arr);
            modalBody.append(table);
  $('.modal-body').html(modalBody); 

        })
```

```css
.table_container {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
        }

        .container::after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
        }

        table {
            margin: 0 auto;

            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        tr {
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        td {
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border: 1px double white;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: light-grey;
            width: 272px;
        }

        .sub_text {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-style: italic;
            color: #0071ce;
            font-weight: 100;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #0071ce;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .header {
            color: #0071ce;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="table_container">
        </div>

        <div class="table_container">
            <table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv">
                <tr>
                    <th>Tab A<input type="checkbox" id=" 1" name="table1" value="table1"
                            onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$133.90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$161.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$53.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$186.20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$3000</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="table_container">
            <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
                <tr>
                    <th>Tab B <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"
                            onchange="myFunction(event)"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$33.90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$161.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$53.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$186.20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$3000</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="table_container">
            <table id="table3" class="checkboxdiv">
                <tr>
                    <th>Tab C<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="table3" value="table3"
                            onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$33.90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$161.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$53.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$186.20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modals to display your differences between your tables as a popup when they selected. Assign modals' close button as a reset button as well via JS.

modals: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Edit:

I couldn't find the line for calling your js file in your code. Can you add  this line to the end of your html-body section? 
You can add a `console.log()` line to your js file, so you can see if your js and html files are connected or not on the browser. (via insperctor-console)
Also, I couldn't find the line that you're activating your modal. You should change its class list. `fade` means it will not display on the browser. You should remove it and add `show` instead.

Edit-2:

I am not familiar with `$` so I am adding the JS which is working. Please try the below things and if there will be a problem, edit your code below and leave me a comment.

in your js file, follow the steps I wrote. You should see an alarm when you click your modal button. You need to fill it up:

```
document.getElementById('modalButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
alert('hi');

  // step - 1: clean the inner of previous modal, if it has
  // step - 2: add the result of comparing two table elements
  // step - 3: remove 'fade' from modal's class and add 'show'
})
```

in your html (add an id to your modal button, it will be easier to select):

`<button type="button" id="modalButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>`

Comment: Yes I try using that but it seems to be not working, I am not getting where i am going wrong

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or not? if not, the modal won't work like that.. you need to write its classes as well.

Comment: yes, i was missing the bootstrap import. Its working now